# Shifting Chart without losing points

Tags: highcharts

I want to shift a chart in another way than addPoint does. You can see what I mean in my JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/TEEdw/3/
When the chart has filled the container and the next point is added, it shifts to the left without losing the first point.

It works fine, but sometimes I can see the chart swapping a little bit. And even worth: when running over a longer time the chart gets lost. It still works, you can see it shifting and updating y in the upper right corner, but the chart is not visible any more. Even the navigator is empty.

So my question is: Is there a better and smarter way to shift the chart this way?

```
data.push([ xTime, prevY ]);            
data.push([ xTime, y ]);
series.setData(data, true);
var faktor = ( (chart.xAxis[0].max - chart.xAxis[0].min) / 60 / 1000 ) * 200;                   
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes( chart.xAxis[0].min + faktor, chart.xAxis[0].max + faktor);
```

Comment: Which steps should I do to replicate this issue, because I'm watiing and observe your example and probelm doens't appear. (Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on a chart with very similar attributes and have run into similar problems. One of the undesired effects of the addPoint() shift flag is that it tries to keep the data set the same size it was initialized with. I'm guessing that is your reason for not using it. It doesn't allow you to grow your data set to a certain size and then start shifting. I had this issue with the shift so I resorted to doing exactly what you are doing. I think this is the generally accepted alternative to addPoint().

But... couple that with the idea that Highchart (or maybe just Highstock) appears to have a max number of data points it will handle. I don't know if it is the same for all charts (or even for all users/browsers) but for me yours seems to disappear when the data count is 1000. See this fiddle: > jsfiddle.net/TEEdw/4/ you can watch the data length grow to 1000 and then the chart disappears. I was running into the same issue on my chart. My solution was more complicated due to other factors in my chart. But a simple solution is to monitor the data count and when it approaches 1000, switch to the addPoint() with shift method. See this fiddle: > jsfiddle.net/TEEdw/5/ There is probably other ways to allow the data set to grow and then shift at a certain point. But this one just used your existing code. You could probably dynamically set the shift flag based on data length and only set it true once the data reaches a certain length.

EDIT: Ok... there is also a plotOptions setting called turboThreshold (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) that can be disabled. It defaults to 1000 (so that makes sense). Setting it to zero allowed your chart to keep going after 1000. See this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/TEEdw/6/

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Setting turboThresdhold: 0 fixes the issue.